# Words to describe the situation in which my diary book has a few fresh pages left

Tags: vocabulary, adjectives, negation, past-participles

I bought a few diary books some time ago.
Each diary book has 60 pages.
I like writing diary, but my diary book only has a few fresh pages left, which means I have to write my diary in a new one very soon.

Given that situation, I am trying to describe it using the words I have learned from school.

Here it is:

> (1). My diary book is about to use up.

But I think (1) can not fully describe my situation, because it can not tell people that my diary book only has a few pages left to write on.

Can you help me please?

Comment: You can use double space `__` (hitting the space button twice) instead of `<br>`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of "fresh pages" you should use "blank pages". Then you could write:

> My diary (book) only has a few blank pages left. I will need to start a new one soon.

or

> My diary (book) is almost full. I will need to start a new one soon.

Also you don't really need "book" in these sentences, because a diary is generally understood to be a book.

Comment: Rather than full, I would probably say "filled up". It's subtle - and full isn't wrong, exactly - but if someone asked why I wanted to buy a new diary, I'd never say, "Because this one's full," I'd say, "Because I've filled this one up."

Comment: @KyleHale That might be regional; I always refer to notebooks as being "full" and not being "filled up". Either one would be perfectly clear to a native speaker, in any case.

Answer (score 7):

Correcting what you were trying to say in your question, I would say:

> My diary is almost used up.

But these sound slightly clearer:

> My diary is almost full.
>   My diary is almost finished

Comment: As a native speaker, I can't think of any more natural way than to say almost full.

Comment: "Filled up" is probably the best specific word choice.

Answer (score 3):

My diary has very few blank pages left; I shall be starting a new one soon.

There are only a few blank pages left, I shall have to start a new book soon.

I wonder if I write very fast I will finish this diary before it runs out.

Comment: In American English I would say "will," not "shall."

Answer (score 3):

I would say either "I'm running out of fresh pages in my diary" or "My diary is running out of fresh pages", except that instead of "fresh pages" I would say "blank pages" or "pages to write on", or simply "pages", since it's implied that diary pages are for writing (unless it's *someone else's* diary). You could also refer to the blank pages as "space [to write]".  For example:

> I'm running out of pages in my diary.
>
> I'm running out of space in my diary.
>
> My diary is running out of space.
>
> My diary is running out of pages.

Answer (score 1):

> **My diary's blank pages are about to run out. So it's time to get a new one.**

or

> **My diary's pages are almost filled up. So it's time to get a new one.**

I think you can convey, what is in your mind with this sentences.

Comment: @kitty: was that helpful ? or solved your problem ?

Comment: The sentence sounds odd to this native British English speaker. It would be better to say "my diary's blank pages", as the pages belong to the diary; and as user 3169 says above, a diary is normally assumed to be a book. "Run out", rather than "finish" sounds better in this context, perhaps because "run out" suggests a resource being depleted. Finally, there's a [comma splice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice) here; a semicolon, or saying "**so** it's time..." would be preferable.

Comment: As a native American speaker, I would never say "about to finish."